# how to use neato with spline and avoid mutual edges overlapping?

Tags: graphviz, overlap, directed-graph, neato

I have a directed graph with ~20 nodes that I need to have their positions fixed. So, I'm using neato to generate my svg file. The problem is that if I use the straight lines, I have edges overlapping some of the nodes. If a set -Gsplines=true -Gsep=1 the edges avoid the nodes nicely but them the mutual nodes (that is, nodes from a -> b and b -> a) are displayed on top of each other...
Below is a piece of it, for example, where edges 9 -> 12 and 12 -> are completely overlapped.
Does anyone know a way around this? I can go with the straight lines that crosses nodes, but if I can manage to avoid them and have the mutual edges displayed separately, would be ideal. Unfortunately, using plain dot is not an option since the fixed position of the nodes is imperative, since my final goal is to put this on top of a map (which I'm doing "by hand" with inkscape). Solutions in other languages (with examples, if possible), are also appreciated.

```
digraph {
7 [width=0.388723, shape=circle, style=filled,pos="-5.3642582,-2.953523!", color="#CCFFFF"];
9 [width=1.02852, shape=circle, style=filled,pos="-9.84668,4.0044438!", color="#CCFF00"];
12 [width=0.337023, shape=circle, style=filled,pos="-9.2490238,1.6804541!", color="#CC9933"];
13 [width=0.315507, shape=circle, style=filled,pos="-7.456055,0.035156!", color="#99FFCC"];
17 [width=0.164396, shape=circle, style=filled,pos="-7.2275394,1.8979026!", color="#33FF99"];

9 -> 7 [penwidth=0.644654, color="#CCFF00"];
9 -> 12 [penwidth=2.04003, color="#CCFF00"];
9 -> 13 [penwidth=1.10067, color="#CCFF00"];
9 -> 17 [penwidth=1.79226, color="#CCFF00"];
12 -> 9 [penwidth=0.5, color="#CC9933"];
12 -> 13 [penwidth=0.75431, color="#CC9933"];
12 -> 17 [penwidth=0.828487, color="#CC9933"];
13 -> 7 [penwidth=0.695661, color="#99FFCC"];
17 -> 13 [penwidth=1.78682, color="#33FF99"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a problem with a particular version of graphviz - here's the output I get with 2.28, and it doesn't display the problems you mentioned.

I added simply `splines=true; sep=1;` in the graph.

[image: graphviz output]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm using the version provided by Ubuntu Central, which is 2.26.3 (Ubuntu 11.10)
I'll try to install the 2.28 and see what happens in my end. ;)

Comment: I've installed version 2.28 and got the same result as you for this sample of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed version 2.28 and got the same result as you for this sample of the data.
Unfortunately, for the complete set it breaks down. Without the splines=true it works fine (with straight lines overlapping nodes, as usual). But when I set splines=true, sep=1 it does not generate the svg properly. Runnig it without -Tsvg, I get a memory related error that starts likes this:

```
 *** glibc detected *** neato: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000001e96c00  ***
 ======= Backtrace: =========
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7a6e6)[0x7f256f1856e6]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6c)[0x7f256f1899cc]
 /usr/local/lib/graphviz/libgvplugin_neato_layout.so.6(freeRouter+0x3e)[0x7f256aa0095e]
 /usr/local/lib/graphviz/libgvplugin_neato_layout.so.6(+0x19e59)[0x7f256a9eee59]
 /usr/local/lib/graphviz/libgvplugin_neato_layout.so.6(splineEdges+0x24d)[0x7f256a9ef3fd]
 /usr/local/lib/graphviz/libgvplugin_neato_layout.so.6(neato_layout+0x532)[0x7f256a9ea6e2]
 /usr/local/lib/libgvc.so.6(gvLayoutJobs+0x91)[0x7f256f6dae61]
 neato[0x400f3c]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7f256f12c30d]
 neato[0x400fad]
 ======= Memory map: ========
```

The complete graph is this one:

```
digraph {
 graph [size="16.68,8.55",resolution="72",bgcolor=transparent];
 1 [width=      0.10000000 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="     13.39800000,     -2.34524000!" color="#FFFFFF"];
 2 [width=      0.59517100 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="      1.70387000,      2.39732000!" color="#FFFFCC"];
 3 [width=      1.02015000 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="      0.71950000,      4.79922000!" color="#FF6600"];
 4 [width=      0.42447300 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="      4.54980430,      2.96880530!" color="#FFFF66"];
 5 [width=      0.86597700 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="      3.76904280,      5.57271100!" color="#FFCCCC"];
 6 [width=      1.51677000 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="     11.65283190,      3.98422860!" color="#FFCC33"];
 7 [width=      0.38872300 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="     -5.36425820,     -2.95352300!" color="#CCFFFF"];
 8 [width=      0.18210900 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="      7.01074180,      4.85747900!" color="#CCFF99"];
 9 [width=      1.02852000 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="     -9.84668000,      4.00444380!" color="#CCFF00"];
10 [width=      0.78439800 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="      0.15527310,      0.75367640!" color="#CCFFFF"];
11 [width=      0.58314700 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="      3.67089810,     -0.14061090!" color="#CC99FF"];
12 [width=      0.33702300 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="     -9.24902380,      1.68045410!" color="#CC9933"];
13 [width=      0.31550700 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="     -7.45605500,      0.03515600!" color="#99FFCC"];
14 [width=      2.10000000 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="      7.83691370,      2.19430460!" color="#99FF66"];
15 [width=      1.35638000 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="     11.44042930,      0.19332270!" color="#CC3399"];
16 [width=      0.37155900 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="      2.31738250,     -2.19430460!" color="#33FFFF"];
17 [width=      0.16439600 shape=circle, style=filled,pos="     -7.22753940,      1.89790260!" color="#33FF99"];
 1 ->   6[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      0.76772236, color="#FFFFFF"];
 1 ->   7[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      0.50000000, color="#FFFFFF"];
 1 ->  15[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      0.57695912, color="#FFFFFF"];
 2 ->   3[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      0.71351528, color="#FFFFCC"];
 2 ->   7[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      0.98261125, color="#FFFFCC"];
 2 ->  10[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      2.98429611, color="#FFFFCC"];
 3 ->   2[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      3.10970125, color="#FF6600"];
 3 ->   4[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      2.19246934, color="#FF6600"];
 3 ->   5[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      3.48380699, color="#FF6600"];
 3 ->   8[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      2.56421761, color="#FF6600"];
 3 ->   9[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      0.86576911, color="#FF6600"];
 3 ->  10[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      3.08433716, color="#FF6600"];
 3 ->  16[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.50759938, color="#FF6600"];
 3 ->  17[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      2.42768450, color="#FF6600"];
 4 ->   2[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      3.52409026, color="#FFFF66"];
 4 ->   3[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.16680621, color="#FFFF66"];
 4 ->   8[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      2.83247875, color="#FFFF66"];
 4 ->  11[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      3.18186134, color="#FFFF66"];
 4 ->  14[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      3.71014548, color="#FFFF66"];
 4 ->  15[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.33899072, color="#FFFF66"];
 5 ->   3[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      0.83007122, color="#FFCCCC"];
 5 ->   8[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      5.11512052, color="#FFCCCC"];
 6 ->   1[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.05435052, color="#FFCC33"];
 6 ->   8[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      2.17017566, color="#FFCC33"];
 6 ->  15[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.78042048, color="#FFCC33"];
 7 ->  13[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.70638297, color="#CCFFFF"];
 8 ->   5[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      3.21975483, color="#CCFF99"];
 9 ->  12[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      2.47722286, color="#CCFF00"];
 9 ->  13[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.41201772, color="#CCFF00"];
 9 ->  17[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      2.31502497, color="#CCFF00"];
10 ->   2[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.44435627, color="#CCFFFF"];
10 ->   7[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.03121586, color="#CCFFFF"];
10 ->  16[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.50003087, color="#CCFFFF"];
11 ->  10[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.72840183, color="#CC99FF"];
11 ->  16[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      2.13382591, color="#CC99FF"];
12 ->   9[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      0.73349271, color="#CC9933"];
12 ->  13[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.50699757, color="#CC9933"];
13 ->   7[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.39745583, color="#99FFCC"];
13 ->  17[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.13347078, color="#99FFCC"];
14 ->   4[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.30211157, color="#99FF66"];
14 ->   5[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.00132679, color="#99FF66"];
15 ->   1[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.32443039, color="#CC3399"];
15 ->   4[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      1.63346112, color="#CC3399"];
15 ->   6[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      2.27386028, color="#CC3399"];
15 ->  14[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      2.67493819, color="#CC3399"];
16 ->  10[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      3.33223069, color="#33FFFF"];
16 ->  11[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      3.32587861, color="#33FFFF"];
17 ->   3[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      0.88032271, color="#33FF99"];
17 ->   9[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      0.56000418, color="#33FF99"];
17 ->  13[arrowshape=vee,penwidth=      2.95412645, color="#33FF99"];
}
```

Comment: On an other computer (windows, graphviz 2.29) I managed to create the graph - I had to replace the line starting with `graph [ ... ` and add all the properties separately (`size="16.68,8.55";
 resolution="72";
 bgcolor=transparent;
 splines=true;
 sep=1;`

Comment: You are using the amd64 or i386 packages?
II just installed the amd64 2.29 version and still get the segmentation fault (I'm on a ia64 machine with the corresponding version of Ubuntu 11.10). For smaller networks (fewer edges but same number of nodes) it works if the sep is small. For instance, with 42 edges I have to set sep=.4 tops. If I set a separation larger than that, it also gives me a segmentation fault or glibc.
I'll have a collaborator of mine try it on her windows machine and see what happens. Meanwhile, I'll try the i386 version on my OS.
Thanks a lot for your help, marapet!

Comment: Finally managed! I cleaned up all graphviz packages and reinstalled the 2.29 amd64 versions of libgraphviz4, librgraphviz-dev and graphviz. Things to note:
1) as with you, I must set the graph attributes separately.
2) I must set sep=.4 to avoid segmentation faults, but the edges have a good separation from the nodes with this already, so it's not a big deal.

marapet, I couldn't be more grateful for your help. You can't imagine how long (and with how many programs) I have been dealing with this dataset.
As a side note, I'm applying the notugly.xsl to the svg output to make it look even better

Comment: I'm glad I could help. notugly.xsl is a very nice addition and easy to add in the workflow.