# Draw splines with neato instead of straight lines

Tags: python, graphviz, neato

I am plotting a data flow graph from within a python program with:

```
g.render('output/data.gv', view=True)
```

Since I need to align the nodes at specific positions, I decided to use `neato` as engine:

```
g = Digraph(engine='neato')
```

However, as `neato` by default draws straight lines rather than splines (as `dot` does) this makes the graph look a bit messy (see below). So is there a way to configure make it draw splines through python code?

Example (file `data.gv`):

```
digraph {
    nop1 [label=nop1 pos="0,6!"]
    o1 [label="o1
ALU" height=0.75 pos="0,5!"]
        nop1 -> o1
    o2 [label="o2
MUL" height=1.75 pos="1,4.5!"]
        nop1 -> o2
    o3 [label="o3
MUL" height=1.75 pos="2,4.5!"]
        nop1 -> o3
    o4 [label="o4
MUL" height=1.75 pos="3,4.5!"]
        nop1 -> o4
    o7 [label="o7
ALU" height=0.75 pos="4,5!"]
        nop1 -> o7
    o5 [label="o5
MUL" height=1.75 pos="0,2.5!"]
        o3 -> o5
        o4 -> o5 
    o6 [label="o6
ALU" height=0.75 pos="1,3!"]
        o4 -> o6
    o8 [label="o8
ALU" height=0.75 pos="0,1!"]
        o3 -> o8
        o5 -> o8
    nop2 [label="nop2
NOP" height=-0.25 pos="0,0!"]
        o1 -> nop2
        o2 -> nop2
        o6 -> nop2
        o7 -> nop2
        o8 -> nop2
}
```

[image: Graph generated by above code]

Comment: Look into `set -Gsplines=true -Gsep=1` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373994/

Comment: I found that already, too but how would I realize this from within python code?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Marichyasana's comment, set the graph_attr to include `-splines=true -sep=1`.

```
    from graphviz import Graph

    # A simple demonstration graph
    g = Graph(name="we", engine='neato')
    g.node('1', pos='1,1!', shape='circle')
    g.node('2', pos='2,1!', shape='circle')
    g.node('3', pos='3,1!', shape='circle')
    g.edge('1', '2')
    g.edge('2', '3')
    g.edge('1', '3')

    # The solution
    g.graph_attr['splines'] = 'true'
    g.graph_attr['sep'] = '1'

    g.format = 'jpg'
    g.render('test', view=False)
```

Without the assignment to graph_attr's change (I do not have sufficient reputation to post images):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkmU1.jpg)

Fixed:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xeGT.jpg)

Increasing separation (`'sep'`) is optional and will push the line further away from the center of other nodes. With too large a value splines will not be used for edges.